# How To Print Sharpoint List Item. NOT all the list

Tags: sharepoint, button, printing

I have a sharepoint list. each time i click on an item the form shows up. I have already customized that form, using Infopath.

What i want is to create a button or something, that wil print that form.

I have used the following but it print many elements except for the form itself..i do not want this.

```
    onclick="window.print();return false;" />


<html>
<head>
<title>Print Test</title>
</head>
<body>


<style type="text/css" media="print">
.printbutton {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

i have read many many articles about it but i cannot get it to work.
what should i do?

Comment: We're talking about the browser's print functionality here not something you can control. The browser can only print something which is somewhere on the screen, so you **will** need to open your InfoPath form to be able to print it. There is no function like "checkmark here to print" - it always needs to open first.

Comment: I tried the following: Created .css file inside site's Assets Folder. the .css contains >> body {visibility:hidden;}
 .print {visibility:visible;} <<  after that i put in the Content Editor >> <form><input type="button" value=" Print this page "
 onclick="window.print();return false;" /></form> <<  i put the ref to the page's header >><link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css"  type="text/css" media="print" /> << f and now i need to assign class="print" to whatever parts i want to be available.  What do you think. Am I in a good way at all? ..if yes..how do I coninue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specify a special area to print . like

```
function printSpecialArea()
{
    var bdhtml=window.document.body.innerHTML; // Save the body content
    var start=""; // Start index of your content
    var end="";//End index of your content
    var prthtml=bdhtml.substring(start , end); // Print Content

    window.document.body.innerHTML=prthtml; // For print
    window.print();
    window.document.body.innerHTML=bdhtml; // Restore the body content
}
```

Hope it useful to you.

Comment: Try to find iframe content where is dialog with form for list item showed.

Comment: Hello and thank you . The code you gave me should be put insinde the Web part?